# How to determine the shape of real quadric surfaces? Use discriminants?

Tags: plotting, functions, algebra

Let $a x^2+2 b x y+c y^2+2 d x+2 e y+f=0$ be the implicit equation that defines
a conic section , where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are real numbers.

I have known from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Conic_sections) how to use 2 discriminants to determine what does the conic section look like.

The code written by me is as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4; e = 5; f = 6;
ConicSection[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := 
  Module[{matrix, firstDiscriminant, secondDiscriminant, expr}, 
   matrix = {{a, b, d}, {b, c, e}, {d, e, f}}; 
   expr = Map[Times @@ # &, Tuples[{x, y, 1}, 2]] . Flatten[matrix]; 
   firstDiscriminant = Det@matrix; secondDiscriminant = b^2 - a*c; 
   Return[{matirx, firstDiscriminant, secondDiscriminant, expr}];];
{matrix, firstDiscriminant, secondDiscriminant, expr} = 
  ConicSection[a, b, c, d, e, f];
getConclusion[firstDiscriminant_, secondDiscriminant_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  If[secondDiscriminant < 0 && firstDiscriminant != 0, 
   Print["the curve either has no real points, or is an ellipse or a \
circle."]];
  If[secondDiscriminant < 0 && firstDiscriminant == 0, 
   Print["the curve is reduced to a single point."]];
  If[secondDiscriminant == 0 && firstDiscriminant != 0, 
   Print["the curve is a parabola"]];
  If[secondDiscriminant == 0 && firstDiscriminant == 0, 
   Print["a double line or two parallel lines."]];
  If[secondDiscriminant > 0 && firstDiscriminant != 0, 
   Print["the curve is a hyperbola"]];
  If[secondDiscriminant > 0 && firstDiscriminant == 0, 
   Print["a pair of intersecting lines."]];]
getConclusion[firstDiscriminant, secondDiscriminant];
ContourPlot[expr == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

**Yes, the programme looks good enough, adding extra Algebraic fingerprint like centrifugation rate seems better.**

---

My question is:

Let $P(x,y,z)$ be a polynomial of degree two in three variables that defines a real quadric surface.

How to use Mathematica to determine the shape of real quadric surfaces?

One demonstration with `Manipulate` is better.

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could use Eigenvalues on the matrix that gives the quadratic part.

Answer (score 1):

Note your formula does define a curve in "D, not a surface in 3D. Anyway, the following procedure can be applied in both cases.

Fist, your polynomial:

```
poly = a x^2 + 2  b  x y + c  y^2 + 2 d  x + 2 e y + f /. {a -> 1, 
   b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6}

6 + 8 x + x^2 + 10 y + 4 x y + 3 y^2
```

To determine the form of the quadrip, I think the easiest way is to to make a coordinate transformation to main axis. Then the behavior can be read from the coefficients of the quadratic terms. The transformation can be done with the procedure below. It takes a polynomial 2. order and returns the same polynomials with main axis variables (note, the determinant of the quadratic coefficient must not be zero):

```
hauptAT[poly_] := 
 Module[{var = Variables[poly], quadrErg, lin, x1, x2, x3, a1, a2, 
   a3 , ev, poly1, var2, c, n},
  n = Length[var];
  as = Table[a[i], {i, n}];
  
  quadrErg[c2_, 
    c1_] := (lin = 
     Select[Coefficient[(var . c2 . var+ c1.var /. 
           Thread[var -> (var - as)]), # ], 
        FreeQ[Alternatives @@ var]] & /@ var;
    as /. Solve[lin == 0, as][[1]]);
  
  var2 = Outer[Times, var, var];
  c2 = Map[If[MatchQ[#, _^2], 1, 1/2] Coefficient[poly, #] & , 
    var2, {2}];
  
  ev = Eigenvectors[c2] // N;
  poly1 = 
   poly  /. Thread[var -> Transpose[ev] . var] // Expand // Chop;
  
  c2 = Map[If[MatchQ[#, _^2], 1, 1/2] Coefficient[poly1, #] & , 
    var2, {2}];
  c1 = Coefficient[poly1, #] & /@ var;
  poly1 /. Thread[var -> (var - quadrErg[c2, c1])]  // Expand// Chop
  ]

poly1 = hauptAT[poly]

131. + 5.8541 x^2 - 0.854102 y^2
```

If the constant term is positive, multiply by: -1

```
-poly

-131. - 5.8541 x^2 + 0.854102 y^2
```

This corresponds to the equation:

```
- 5.8541 x^2 + 0.854102 y^2 == 131
```

Now, if both coefficients on the right side are positive, we have an ellipse. If One is negative, a hyperbola: Extreme cases appear if the constant term is zero. Then if the both coefficients have the same sign, only the origin is a solution, if they differ, we have 2 crossing lines.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' find that, so I implement one by myself.

$\color{red}{\text{But it fails on some cases, e.g.} P(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z}$

Any help would be appreciated.

```
ConvertPolynomialToQuadraticForm[polynomial_, variables_List] := 
  Module[{rules, matrixSize, matrix}, 
   rules = CoefficientRules[polynomial, variables];
   matrixSize = Length[variables];
   matrix = ConstantArray[0, {matrixSize, matrixSize}];
   Do[With[{num = rules[[ruleIndex, 1]], 
      coeff = rules[[ruleIndex, 2]]}, 
     singleVariablePos = Position[num, 2];
     If[Length[singleVariablePos] > 0, 
      matrix[[singleVariablePos[[1, 1]], singleVariablePos[[1, 1]]]] =
        coeff;
      Continue[]];
     pos = Position[num, 1];
     matrix[[pos[[1, 1]], pos[[2, 1]]]] = coeff/2;
     matrix[[pos[[2, 1]], pos[[1, 1]]]] = coeff/2;], {ruleIndex, 
     Length[rules]}];
   matrix];
polynomialDegree[expr_] := 
  Max[0, Max[Total@*First /@ CoefficientRules[expr]]];
Q4[x_, y_, z_, t_] := Module[{d}, d = 2;
   t^d*P[x/t, y/t, z/t] // FullSimplify // Expand];
Q3[x_, y_, z_] := 
  Module[{Q4ins}, Q4ins = Q4[x, y, z, t]; Q4ins /. {t -> 0}];
```

```
getConclusion[Delta3_, Delta4_] := Module[{},
  If[Delta4 == 0, 
   Print["the surface has a singular point, possibly at infinity. If \
there is only one singular point, the surface is a cylinder or a \
cone. If there are several singular points the surface consists of \
two planes, a double plane or a single line."]];
  If[Delta4 > 0 && Delta3 != 0, 
   Print["the surface is a paraboloid, which is hyperbolic"]];
  If[Delta4 > 0 && Delta3 == 0, 
   Print["the surface is one-sheet hyperboloid."]];
  If[Delta4 < 0 && Delta3 != 0, 
   Print["the surface is a paraboloid, which is elliptic"]];
  If[Delta4 < 0 && Delta3 == 0, 
   Print["the surface is either an ellipsoid or a two-sheet \
hyperboloid???????WHICH ONE DOES IT IS????"]];
  If[Delta4 > 0, 
   Print["this is a ruled surface that has a negative Gaussian \
curvature at every point."]];
  If[Delta4 < 0, 
   Print["it has a positive Gaussian curvature at every point."]];
  ]
```

```
P[x_, y_, z_] := 
  x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2 + 4 x*y + 5 x*z + 6 y*z + 7 x + 8 y + 9 z + 10;
Q4Instance = Q4[x, y, z, t];
Q3Instance = Q3[x, y, z];
PInstance = P[x, y, z];
Delta4 = Det@ConvertPolynomialToQuadraticForm[Q4Instance, {x, y, z, t}]
Delta3 = Det@ConvertPolynomialToQuadraticForm[Q3Instance, {x, y, z}]
getConclusion[Delta3, Delta4];
ContourPlot3D[
 PInstance == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

**Yes, the programme looks good enough, adding extra useful Algebraic fingerprint seems better.**